# Why Misnah Sanhedrin 4:5 and sura 5:32 is so similar

Tags: quran

I somehow come across a Question in Quora that claim did Muhammad(sw)copied from  Thalmud as Sura 5:32 and Misnah Sanhedrin 4:5 is too similar,I dont have much knowledge about it so after googling I told if Misnah is Oral torah than God just confirmed it in Quran but she show me this "English Explanation of Mishnah Sanhedrin 4:5:1" https://www.sefaria.org/English_Explanation_of_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.4.5.1?lang=bi, What does it mean?Was this jewish law created by jewish rabbi and not oral torah?She also mocked that Quran challenged no one would be able to produce a work like it but people already produced something like that way before Quran and Quran copied it. Actually what is this misnah sanhedrin  and how to reconcile this with Quran?

Comment: Verse 5:32 is explicit that it is mentioning a law also given to the Jews! And we don't trust Jewish records of the Torah or scripture. Nothing prevents the possibility this was something revealed to one of their prophets but not written down until it was recorded in the speech of this rabbi

Comment: Its so confusing, I haven’t found a single good refutation in internet after searching .

Comment: probably because the entire claim depends on the notion that the Oral Torah and their rabbis' sayings are accurately recorded, and it is quite clear Muslims reject that.

Comment: Do you see even the back story is very similar,Jews say that rabbis make this law as Cain killed his brother so the his brothers bloods flowed, not blood but bloods so rabbis came to conclusion for that law,https://www.sefaria.org/English_Explanation_of_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.4.5.1?lang=bi see Quran also say that Allah made this law cause Cain killed his brother, look Quran 5:27-32.

Comment: Yes the Quran is very explicit this was a law given to Bani Israil using the evidence of Cain. So, I am not sure why this is being used as if it is against the Quran. This whole commentary confirms the Quran's statement. The problem is your assumption that this rabbi's interpretation was entirely original and had no basis in a revelation given to one of their prophets, so the rabbi made this law himself. That is baseless extrapolation based on too much trust of Jewish records.

Comment: The verse 5:32 begins "Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that [...]"

Comment: Well,It's not my assumption,It's her, the one who was arguing with me said that as Babylonian thalmud is older than Quran, It's the source of Quran.Again I heard this babylonian Thalmud was still editing in 6 and 7CE so it also can be that they borrowed from Muslim as they lived with Muslims in 7 CE and we Don't have any evidence as most of the manuscripts burned in 1242.

Comment: The wording is different between them . At any rate. Do we have mishnah sanheddrin manuscripts dated before 7th century which contain this statement ? Perhaps it is a treachery invented by the jews. A slim possibility perhaps but we can’t discount anything.

Answer (score 0):

Quran 5:32 says

> Because of that We ordained for the Children of Israel: that whoever kills a person—unless it is for murder or corruption on earth—it is as if he killed the whole of mankind; and whoever saves it, it is as if he saved the whole of mankind. Our messengers came to them with clarifications, but even after that, many of them continue to commit excesses in the land.

What you cited is a comment on the comment on Genesis 4:15

> But the Lord said to him, “Not so e ; anyone who kills Cain will suffer vengeance seven times over.” Then the Lord put a mark on Cain so that no one who found him would kill him.

The Mishnah Torah is oral (scholarly) tradition and comment on the Torah. It has been written down by Jews later than Jesus but before Muhammad according to older oral traditions and common fiqh. Orthodox and Conservative Jews consider it part of the Torah. The Jews call it the "Oral Torah", not claiming that all written in there is part of the Torah but containing old traditions said to root in the teachings of Mose. It says

> The court tells the witnesses: Therefore, Adam the first man was created alone, to teach you that with regard to anyone who destroys one soul from the Jewish people, i.e., kills one Jew, the verse ascribes him blame as if he destroyed an entire world, as Adam was one person, from whom the population of an entire world came forth.

Indeed, we have here one of the few examples where the Quran cites something that is only contained in the Oral Torah as part of the Torah, and to my knowledge the only one where it is confirming it to be ordained to the Children of Israel.

Note that the Quran is not the first but the last revelation, essentially confirming what has been revealed before. So do not be astonished to find many many things that have been said before.

Comment: Well u may not know this commentary section say jews rabbis derived this law from  able's bloods (not blood but bloods, which means able's  future generation also killed when he died) and not oral torah but I think they lied as they always hide truth from sculpture

Comment: What you say is not the Jewish majority opinion. A lot has been said but the Jewish chain only reaches back to the  rabbi who last said it. Nobody really knows more...